# Is there a bug in integer division (%) Python?

Tags: integer-division

Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > 7%5
> > >       2
> > >       8%5
> > >       3
> > >       6%5
> > >       1

Comment: What's wrong here? 7%5 means "The rest of the euclidian division of 7 by 5 is 2"

Comment: Integer division in python3 is `//`

Answer (score 1):

**Division /**

With integers as input, the division will give you an integer result (**Python2+**)

```
>>> 7/5
1
>>> 8/5
1
>>> 10/5
2
```

With at least one non-integer as input (**Python2+**), you will have a non-integer result.

```
>>> 10/1.5
6.666666666666667
>>> 10/4.0
2.5
```

**Python3**: The integer division is `//`

```
>>> 10/4 # Python 3
2.5
>>> 10//4 # Python 3 integer division
2
```

**Modulo % (= remainder)**

The modulo is the remainder of the integer division

```
>>> 7%5 # = What is the remainder of the division of 7 by 5
2
>>> 8%5
3
>>> 10%5
0
```

Comment: `/` is only integer division in python2.

Comment: That is correct Matt, updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Modulo operation `7%5 = 2` its correct 
For integer division you have to use "//" eg: `7//5`.If you want result in float you can use `7/5` .